# PHP - output buffering with global variables in included file

Tags: php, output-buffering

I am trying to include a file using output buffering as follows. But cannot use global variables inside function of an included files.

Main.php

```
function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        require $filename;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}
```

test.php - included file:

```
include_once 'settings.php';  // defines many global variables like $obj1, $ojb2

// some processing
test();
// some processing

function test() {
    global $obj1, $obj2;

    // using $obj1
    $obj1->function_obj1();  // $obj1 is not defined
}
```

Comment: Try adding single quotes before and after the file settings.php i.e. Make it  include_once 'settings.php'

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Where have you declared your class and where is its instantiation ?

Comment: Main.php is the main file where I am including test.php. It is not a class. Does it have to be a class ?

Comment: Of course !! You are calling function_obj1(); but you have not instantiation it. In fact you have not even created a class for it.

Comment: please have a look at my answer and do consider marking it correct and upvoting it , if it were helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a class and then create functions in it. For example let your file name be main.php. Then make this

```
class main 
{
function __construct(){
 // define a constructor 
}
function xyz($a1, $a2 ....$an){
// perform operations 
} 
}
```

Now make another file make another class. Let's say your file name is main2.php

```
require_once 'main.php';
class main2{

private $a1;

function __construct()
{
     $this->a1 = new main();
}

function abc()
{
 $fun = $this->a1->xyz($a1, $a2 ....$an);
// and now perform operations 
}
}
```

After the class ends, you can call the functions with the same concept used in the constructor right after the class ends.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Took me a while to change all the classes and scripts to fit this structure.